# Adicionar CSS ao clicar em um botão que vai para outra página

Tags: javascript, inserir, onclick

Preciso adicionar altura em uma div quando eu clicar em um botão, só que tem um porém essa div fica em outra página e é ai que eu não estou conseguindo fazer, mostrarei como eu fiz no código abaixo se alguém puder ajudar

**CÓDIGO**

```
$('.close-reveal-modal').click(function(){
    $('#site .makingof .slide').addClass('insere-altura');
});​
```

Explicando o código: Quando eu clico em .close-reveal-modal ele volta pra página index.php e insere a classe "insere-altura" juntamente com a classe slide.

Answer (score 1):

É um pouco complicado conseguir esse comportamento só com javascript

uma solução seria usar localStorage:

- Gravar algum tipo de informação em localstorage e na pagina index checar a localstorage se a informação estiver presente adicionar a classe.
  Ex:

```js
// No Index
$(function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem('close-reveal-modal-clicked')){
       $('#site .makingof .slide').addClass('insere-altura');
  }
});


$('.close-reveal-modal').click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem('close-reveal-modal-clicked', true);
});​
```

Comment: não deu muito certo,o que acontece é que eu tenho na página principal um carrossel vertical com um monte de thumb, quando clica em um thumb desses vai para a página interna, quando a pessoa clica no botão de voltar, ele não voltava na mesmo fileira de thumbs então eu fiz uma ancora e cada li tem 6 thumbs e eu chamei de id="box'" por ex, quando eu implementei isto funcionou ele voltou pra fileira mas grudado no topo da página. O que falta agora é não ficar no topo da página, isso que eu não estou conseguindo

Comment: Coloca um exemplo ai ou manda um print da tela de como está e como era para ficar, para entender melhor como seria

Comment: este link é a imagem de como deve ficar quando retornar da outra página http://progdesenv.com.br/img/comoepraficar.jpg
este link é de como está atualmente quando eu retorno da outra página http://progdesenv.com.br/img/comoesta.jpg
Perceba que os thumbs ainda estão na mesma posição, o problema é que o menu é fixo e quando eu setei para voltar como ancora ele vai para o topo do elemento assim ficando atrás do menu

Comment: e se o usuario desabilitar o armazenamento local como é que fica? hah...